# How to replace order.first by current_order ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have trouble to find the solution to my problem, i want to replace order.first in my paypal_express_helper.rb :

```
  def get_totals(order)
    subtotal = Order.first.subtotal
    return subtotal
  end
```

by the order that is assigned to the user.
Here's my model/order.rb :

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order_status
  has_many :order_items
  before_create :set_order_status
  before_save :update_subtotal

  def subtotal
    order_items.collect { |oi| oi.valid? ? (oi.quantity * oi.unit_price) : 0 }.sum
  end

private

  def set_order_status
    self.order_status_id = 1
  end

  def update_subtotal
    self[:subtotal] = subtotal
  end
end
```

Comment: You'd need to pass in the user's current order to the helper

Comment: I see you are already passing **order** object to **get_totals()**. Replace `Order.first.subtotal` with `order.subtotal`

Comment: with order.subtotal, i have : "undefined method `subtotal' for nil:NilClass". with @order =current_order
        subtotal = @order.subtotal, it looks run, is it the good way ?

Comment: if @order has the order you are interested in, then yes!

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be something like:

```
def get_totals(order)
 order.subtotal
end
```

in which case not sure why you would not just use `order.sub_total`